# how to sort value in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Hi could you please tell me how to sort value in xslt ?

here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRJq/1

**XML**

```
    <livescore gn="192.168.24.87">
        <calendar potime="715">
          <test matchstatus="Match Ended" name="ccc" matchnumber="Match 1"/>
            <test matchstatus="adsds" name="bb" matchnumber="Match 2"/>
            <test matchstatus="Match Ended" name="aaa" matchnumber="Match 4"/>
            <test matchstatus="Match Ended" name="bbb" matchnumber="Match 3"/>
        </calendar>
    </livescore>
```

**code**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
        <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

        <xsl:template match="/">
          <hmtl>
            <head>
              <title>New Version!</title>
            </head>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="livescore/calendar/test[@matchstatus ='Match Ended']"/>
          </hmtl>
        </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="livescore/calendar/test[@matchstatus ='Match Ended']" >

    <h1><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h1>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:transform>
```

**output**

```
<h1>ccc</h1>
   <h1>aaa</h1>
   <h1>bbb</h1>
```

**expected output**

```
<h1>aaa</h1>
       <h1>bbb</h1>
       <h1>ccc</h1>
```

I tried this line

```
<xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring-after(matchnumber,' '))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
```

But not working

Comment: <xsl:sort select="//@name" />

Comment: using `matchnumber` I need t sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT, you only need to add the missing `@` to your attempt and make it:

```
<xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring-after(@matchnumber,' '))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRJq/2

Answer (score -2):

```
<xsl:sort select="//@matchnumber"/>
```

Comment: please remove this answer